# What is the difference between Partition and Division?

Tags: graphs, terminology, sets

While reading graph theory, I came across different definitions where they use partitions and divisions, I was wondering, are these terms same or different?

Can anyone explain me their difference in Set Theory?

I know this is a simple question but anyone hardly talk about it but they always make here a mistake.

Comment: I'm having doubts about the term "Graph Division"... may be, you mean "Graph Subdivision"?

Comment: Please give a source, there are different terminologies and the meaning for sets might not be the meaning for graphs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I will explain this with an example :**

*Consider a set $S$ which contains a collections of sets with a constant k such that:*
$$ S = \{ \{S_1\}, \{S_2\}, \{S_3\},\{S_4\},..........\{S_k\} \}$$

#### In Partition of Set S :

Then we can form the set again by

$ S=S_1\cup S_2\cup S_3\cup S_4...........\cup S_k$

$where\ S_i\cap S_j = \phi$

$and\ i\neq j\ and\ i,j\in \mathcal{N} $

#### In Division of Set S :

We just have this

$ S=S_1\cup S_2\cup S_3\cup S_4...........\cup S_k$

Comment: The definitions of $S$ (or rather the $S_i$) does not match its (their) use! Furthermore, do you hae any source for this terminology (I mean division; partition is fine)?

Comment: Division is not a standard concept in combinatorics. There is no reason to assume that division has this meaning.